# Using Wordpress as a CMS - advice on doing it for localhost?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, customization

I have a plain-vanilla install of Wordpress on localhost, virtual host in Apache set to:

```
127.0.0.1 myradiostationhere.com
127.0.0.1 www.myradioanytown.co.uk
```

and the virtual host works.

However, I don't want to use it as a blog, but as a CMS like here:

http://www.brmb.co.uk/

and

http://www.brmb.co.uk/schedule/

(basically, any pages on that site are database-driven Wordpress pages, not blogs).

I'm not asking how to create pages etc. - I understand that - but rather if anyone knows of the best way to do this.

I'm trying to emulate their look, but with similar CSS stylesheets, as per:

> Fair dealing in a work for the purposes of private study or research (s. 29)

under Copyright, Design and Patents Act 1988 (that's the legal bit out the way).

Would I need to edit the PHP files in order to get this to work in the way I intend to?

Anyone here had experience of custom Wordpress CMS design/installs, and how would you recommend I go about this?

(note: This **isn't** for a live radio station site, it's a development/testing site on localhost!)

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to create [WordPress theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

You will need a bit of PHP editing, but mostly of the copy-and-paste variety (to get you started).

Another option is to download a similar free theme or even buy one.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did check for themes, but nothing suitable turned up - I was trying to create my localhost version of the aforementioned site.